# MS Access 2003 to SQL 2012 conversion?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, migration, data-migration

I am working as a DBA and my manager asked me to convert about 46 databases, currently in Access 2003 format, and each containing records Above one Lac.

Can I convert it directly to MS SQL 2012, or first convert Access 2003 to MS Access 2010 and then convert it to MS SQL server? What will be the best way to convert my databases, since there is no front end and we only use back end databases for storing records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that you need to convert the databases to Access 2010.

Have a look at:

[SQL Server Migration Assistant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh313039.aspx) for Access.

Alternatively, Management Studio has an Import Data tool I understand.